# SYN Flood Traffic Volume requirement

Tags: python, security, syn

I wrote a SYN flood script for an assessment and I can see its traffic both spoofed and response flowing, but no effect apart from a slight rise in throughput ( 5 - 8 kbps).

My initial assumption was just that the rate of traffic is just not sufficient.

***So how much traffic is sufficient ?***

Do modern SYN floods need to be distributed to achieve the right volume

or can a single source spoofing addresses generate the desired result with, maybe larger packets?

my name is a joke btw - *CyberSec student

Comment: Most TCP/IP implementations implement SYN-flood protection.

Comment: Yep of course, but say a system was vulnerable

Comment: You probably need a botnet to overwhelm modern servers.